# PHP Property exists in class

Tags: php, properties, static-members

Hey guys I'm having a weird problem with `$this` not being passed around my code, and I'm hoping
someone can help me, structure is below:

```
Class 
{
    protected _foo = '';

    .........


    self::_setSessionsToProperties('_foo', array('access_token','instance_url'));

    ..........

    protected static function _setSessionsToProperties($property, $setter)
    {
        self::_validateApprovedSessions($setter);

        if (isset($this->$property) || property_exists($this, $property)) 
        {
            foreach ($setter as $set) { $this->$property->$set; }
        }

        return $this;
    }
```

`Undefined variable: this`

In order to get this working though I have to actually **pass** `$this` as a param string, which
seems extremely counter intuitive?

```
    self::_setSessionsToProperties($this, '_foo', array('access_token','instance_url'));

    ..........

    protected static function _setSessionsToProperties($this, $property, $setter)
```

what's going on here??

Comment: You can't use `$this` in static functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$this` only exists in an *object context*. Since your class methods are `static` you don't have an object. Hence no `$this`. Make your methods not static and instantiate an object.

Also see [How Not To Kill Your Testability Using Statics](http://kunststube.net/static/).

Answer (score 1):

static methods exist outside of the scope of $this in pretty much all OO languages, this is why they can be called without having to init an instance of the class. you either have to pass it, or store it as a static variable somewhere else to be able to reference it.